# to get the number of files recursively

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count the number of  *.tmp files in the computer. When I click on a button the labelbox should start increasing the count number for each search of .tmp file. my below coding does not seems to be working.

Any help is much appreciated.
Also when I click on button to get the number of tmp files; the lable box should start showing the increase in count like 1,2,,,,,56,,89,,,etc rather than showing just the total number of files.

```
namespace finalclean {

public partial class FinalClean : Form {

    public FinalClean() {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int count = 0; 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

       String path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"c:\windows");

       try {

          foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {

               foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath)) {

                   string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                   if (filename.Equals("*.tmp")) {
                       count++;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
         catch (System.Exception excpt) {
             //Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
         }
       textBox1.Text = (count.ToString());
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Look at the [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it doesn't report progress unfortunately.

Comment: @AntonSizikov It retuns `Enumerable` so you can report progress.

Comment: `String path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"c:\windows");` This is meaningless.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Hm, you're right, it's not a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
var count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Windows\", "*.tmp", 
                      SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

Comment: the problem is that we can't report progress here.

Comment: Thank you...I ll try to implement this

Comment: @AntonSizikov you can if you remove the count and aggregate the results in a loop where you also post the progress. Because the IEnumerable is lazily evaluated while you enumerate it.

Comment: Well that's what @PraveenGowda was asking for. My point was that your solution is not complete.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error "system.IO.Directory does not contain a definition for enumerate files" . I tried installing .NET Framework 3.5,4,4.5.2. But no luck. I'm using visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're not visiting all the directories, but only the fist one (C:\Windows).

If you make it recursive it can do the trick for you.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new Visitor();
        myClass.OnNewFileFound +=Progress;
        myClass.CountTmpFiles();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Progress(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i); //update textbox here
    }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public event Action<int> OnNewFileFound;
    private int count = 0;

    public int CountTmpFiles()
    {
        var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"c:\windows");
        VisitDir(path);
        return count;
    }

    private void VisitDir(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                VisitDir(directory); //recursive call here
            }
            foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.tmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                count++;
                if (OnNewFileFound != null)
                {
                    OnNewFileFound(count);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, if you're only counting files, then I doesn't make sense to write your own code. You just use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` as Andrew and Hamlet Hakobyan suggested.

Comment: Thanks..let me try both